# Unable to open chrome browser, code as below

Tags: webdriver

```
public class Chrome 
{

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

@Before   
public void setup()   
{   
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop\\Downloads");   
driver.get("http://google.com");   
driver.manage().window().maximize();   
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);   
}     

@Test
public void test()

{
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='menu-item-21']/a")).click();    
}}
```

> Error java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver
>   executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property;
>   for more information, see
>   https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest
>   version can be downloaded from
>   http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html

```
at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:199)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:109)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$0(ChromeDriverService.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:137)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:296)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:88)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:116)
    at com.example.tests.Chrome.<init>(Chrome.java:15)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:217)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:266)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Comment: Using the latest version of chrome driver only....

Answer (score 0):

Please set the complete path of chrome driver instead of the directory of chromedriver

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe");
```

Comment: Changed the path but still same error is appearing. (System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe");)

Comment: @user6284292 can you copy driver.exe to system32 folder and re-run the test after commenting the line where you set driver location?

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing the driver after setting the system property. Please find the sample code below.

```
public class Chrome 
{
    WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeSuite  
    public void setup()   
    {   
         System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop\\Downloads");
         // Initializing the chromdriver here
         driver = new ChromeDriver();
         driver.get("http://google.com");   
         driver.manage().window().maximize();   
         driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);   
    }     
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Should set chrome driver path in system property..

```
public class Chromes 
{
    WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeSuite  
    public void setup()   
    {   
         System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe");
         // Initializing the chromdriver here
         driver = new ChromeDriver();
         driver.get("http://google.com");   
         driver.manage().window().maximize();   
         driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);   
    }     
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Tried again & copied the file from above path to any folder in desktop and it worked. The problem is the folder or path where the .exe was present.

SO if you face this kind of problem then please copy the chromedriver.exe fle and place it in some other folder and try again.

Thanks!